# Matlab: iterate through image blocks

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, image-processing, iterator

I would like to divide an image into 8 by 6 blocks and then from each block would like to get the average of red, green and blue values then store the average values from each block into an array. Say that if I have image divided into 4 blocks the result array would be:

```
A = [average_red, average_green, average_blue,average_red, ...
  average_green, average_blue,average_red, average_green, ...
  average_blue,average_red, average_green, average_blue,...
  average_red, average_green, average_blue,]
```

The loop I have created looks very complicated, takes a long time to run and I'm not even sure if it's working properly or not as I have no clue how to check. Is there any simpler way to implement this.

Here is the loop:

```
[rows, columns, ~] = size(img);

[rows, columns, ~] = size(img);

rBlock = 6;
cBlock = 8;
NumberOfBlocks = rBlock * cBlock;

bRow = ceil(rows/rBlock);
bCol = ceil(columns/cBlock);

row = bRow;
col = bCol;

r = zeros(row*col,1);
g = zeros(row*col,1);
b = zeros(row*col,1);

n = 1;
cl = 1;
rw = 1;

for x = 1:NumberOfBlocks

    for i = cl : col
        for j = rw : row
         % some code
        end
    end

    %some code
    if i == columns && j ~= rows
        cl = 1;
        rw = j - (bRow -1);
        col = (col - col) + bCol;
        row = row + bRaw;

    elseif a == columns && c == rows
        display('done');
    else
        cl = i + 1;
        rw = j - (bRow -1);
        col = col + col;
        row = row + row;
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are only 48 block, you may use simple for loop iterating blocks. (I think it's going to be fast enough).

Here is my code:

```
%Build test image
img = double(imresize(imread('peppers.png'), [200, 300]));

[rows, columns, ~] = size(img);

rBlock = 6;
cBlock = 8;
NumberOfBlocks = rBlock * cBlock;

bRow = ceil(rows/rBlock);
bCol = ceil(columns/cBlock);

idx = 1;

A = zeros(1, rBlock*cBlock*3);

for y = 0:rBlock-1
    for x = 0:cBlock-1
        %Block (y,x) boundaries: (x0,y0) to (x1,y1)
        x0 = x*bCol+1;
        y0 = y*bRow+1;
        x1 = min(x0+bCol-1, columns); %Limit x1 to columns
        y1 = min(y0+bRow-1, rows);    %Limit y1 to rows

        redMean   = mean2(img(y0:y1, x0:x1, 1));    %Mean of red pixel in block (y,x)
        greenMean = mean2(img(y0:y1, x0:x1, 2));    %Mean of green pixel in block (y,x)
        blueMean  = mean2(img(y0:y1, x0:x1, 3));    %Mean of blue pixel in block (y,x)

        %Fill 3 elements of array A.
        A(idx)   = redMean;
        A(idx+1) = greenMean;
        A(idx+2) = blueMean;

        %Advance index by 3.
        idx = idx + 3;
    end
end
```